# AnimeJS: Cómo puedo trasladarX a una coordenada exacta?

Tags: javascript, animación, animate.css, animated

la propiedad translatex de animejs traslada el target añadiendo a el valor x que ya tiene
por ejemplo si el objeto está en x30 si escribo translatex: 10, llevará el objeto a x40 pues 0 es la posición inicial
y si quisiera que en vez de añadir con respecto a la posición origial, quisiera que se trasladara a la posición x que yo desee, en el caso del ejemplo que pasara de x30 a x10

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.